# Why do Bitcoin API services offer Block details?

Tags: blockchain, api, block

I understand having APIs around addresses and transactions, but I'm less clear why I need to know what's happening with a Block(s). This is to confirm one's transactions? Might someone provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

E.g. for debugging purposes, for miners, for parties who work directly with Bitcoin protocol.

"I see only block X on my local bitcoind, but the latest on blockchain.info is Y".

Application developers are less interested about blocks.

Comment: And miners need to know so they can pick what to work on?

Comment: You get the same information from raw bitcoin network. It is just in more readable format.

Comment: Mikko, what kind of information specifically do miners need in a more readable format?

Comment: I think the last block would be most useful information to check if their bitcoind is still following the network correctly.